# AWS MSK Connector - Kafka topic to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using AWS MSK.

I want to have a connector that will take messages from a Kafka topic and send them to S3 bucket.

The Kafka topic contains **protobuf** messages. The messages are from **different types** and can be changed during runtime.I have a Kafka header the holds the type (Ex.): `{"type":"Event97"}`

The generated files in the bucket should be in **parquet** format.

The generated file in the bucket should contain the event type as prefix. (Ex.):
**Event97/2022/02/19/23/<random_value_goes_here>.parquet**

I was looking at Confluent [connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/overview.html) and noticed I have the following challenges:

1. I will have to implement a [Partitioner](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/overview.html#s3-sink-pluggable-partitioner) since I cant find a ready to use partitioner that can create the file name I need (**Event97/..**)
2. Since AWS Schema registry does not support protobuf, I dont know how to convert the proto byte array into parquet.

I can solve #1 but I have no idea how to overcome #2

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) There's already open PRs for a "field and time partitioner" in the Confluent github that you can pull from 2) Parquet writer requires an Avro schema. You'd need to write your own converter to deserialize Protobuf into Avro, then use the Parquet `format.class`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks. About the parquet converting. I thought about the following: Dump the Java POJO into JSON and produce it to topic, The convertor will analyze the JSON and generate AVRO Schema on the fly --> Convert to parquet. Make sense?

Comment: I'm confused what's converting JSON to Avro. Connect doesn't do this, out of the box. I recall there being a json to avro Connect transform project on Github. But, If you have full control over the Java code, serialize the POJO to Avro directly...

Comment: aws schema registry supports protobuf now (json, avro, protobuf)